# How to get the data from the json

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get to the [name] (either once at a time or to all of them) in the json but I don't know how to do that, I've tried fiddling a bit with the code e.g. `$json->Array[0]->name`, but that doesn't work. Pls help. Thank you in advance for your answers.

-HeavyMalding

The code:

```
//the json output after decoding:
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => IMG_7013.JPG [full_path] => IMG_7013.JPG [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => F:\XAMPP\tmp\php7772.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 16303899 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => IMG_7738.JPG [full_path] => IMG_7738.JPG [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => F:\XAMPP\tmp\php781F.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 9498238 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => IMG_7792.JPG [full_path] => IMG_7792.JPG [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => F:\XAMPP\tmp\php786E.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 10818478 ) )
```

Comment: `$json[0]->name` since its an *array* of objects.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear enough. If you want to convert a json output to array use the example below.

```php
<?php

$json = 'your json code';
$json = json_decode($json,true);

foreach($json as $row)
{
    $name = $row['name'];
    
    echo $name.'<br>';
}

// ONE ROW

$name = $json[0]['name'];

echo $name;

?>
```

Comment: Please do not answer duplicate questions.  This question is asked nearly everyday.  We try to close and remove obvious duplicates from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works perfectly. I didn't find an answer eventhough there were similar post to mine, so that's why I asked a separate question. There wasn't a post where you would decode a json from a file array that you get when you upload files and encode them into json.